# Is it possible to implement Excel-like sorting widget in react-table component?

Tags: reactjs, filtering, react-table

I'm using [react-table](https://react-table.js.org) component for displaying and filtering of my dataset. My filters look like the following:

[image]

As you can see from the image above each column can provide component for filtering (either `input` and `select`).

Now, I need to implement excel-like filter that looks like this:

[image]

What I've came up so far is implementing a custom component for showing desired widget and positioning it absolute related to header title:

```
<ReactTable
   columns={[
       ....
       {
          Header: "Name",
          accessor: "name",
          Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) =>
          <ExcelFilter
             onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}
             styles={{position: 'absolute', top: '0', right: 0}}
             value={filter}
          />
       }
   ]}
   ...
/>
```

Is it acceptable approach to solving my task (especially with CSS positioning) or there are better approaches to archive this?